Using @Value inside of `BeanPostProcessor` is not supposed to work?
In Spring Documentation (bottom of the page) it says:

The @Autowired, @Inject, @Value, and @Resource annotations are handled by Spring BeanPostProcessor implementations. This means that you cannot apply these annotations within your own BeanPostProcessor or BeanFactoryPostProcessor types (if any). These types must be 'wired up' explicitly by using XML or a Spring @Bean method.

However I had no problem using @Autowired and @Value within my BeanPostProcessor implementation, e.g. the following code works:
# in application.properties
application.name=demo

@Component
public class DemoPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Value("${application.name}")
    String applicationName;

    @PostConstruct
    void postConstruct() {
        System.out.println("===>" + applicationName); // Corectly prints `===>demo`
    }
}

Does anyone know if the documentation is wrong or am I missing sth?

@Value should be private field to make it work

@SusobhanDas To make what work?

@SusobhanDas even if we change it to private still it's same

have you check if the bean is initial after the main run? If it not, the problem may come up with the BeanPostProcessor

The code look OK, do you forget to add application.name in application.properties? The regular value is spring.application.name

@NguyenManhCuong - the code is working, I don't need help making it work. My question is why is the code working despite the documentation stating that this is NOT supposed to work?
